# How to invoke method only from interface and method name?

Tags: c#, reflection

In my program, we referenced another assembly, and there is an implement instance in that assembly definitely. So we want to invoke its method at run-time. We have known the interface and method name, but the implement instance name is not certainly. How I can invoke method only from interface and method name?

```
Type outerInterface = Assembly.LoadAssembly("AnotherAssemblyFile").GetTypes()
     .Single(f => f.Name == "ISample" && f.IsInterface == true);
Object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(outerInterface);
MethodInfo mi = outerInterface.GetMethod("SampleMethod");
var result = mi.Invoke(instance, new object[]{"you will see me"});
```

The exception is thrown:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Cannot create an instance of an interface.
```

The referenced assembly code is here:

```
namespace AnotherAssembly
{
    public interface ISample
    {
        string SampleMethod(string name);
    }

    public class Sample : ISample
    {
        public string SampleMethod(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}--{1}", name, "Alexsanda");
        }
    }
}
```

But the reflection part not work, I am not sure how I can make it work well.

Edit: I don't know the instance name clearly, only know the interface name and method name. But I know there is an implement class from the interface in that assembly definitely.

Comment: Please provide exception details

Comment: You cannot create instance of interface. You should create instance of class which implements interface. I.e. `Sample` in your case

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance(outerInterface);`? You're trying to create instance of an interface? You should be looking for its implementations instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message is really clear: you *cannot* create an instance of an interface. Imagine if you wrote...

```
var x = new ISample()
```

... In normal code. It makes no sense *at all*.

The error stems from these lines of code...

```
Type outerInterface = Assembly.LoadAssembly("AnotherAssemblyFile").GetTypes()
     .Single(f => f.Name == "ISample" && f.IsInterface == true);
Object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(outerInterface);
```

... In the above listing you find the interface *itself* and then attempt to instantiate it.

What you really want to do is find a type that *implements* the interface and instantiate that instead...

```
Type type = Assembly.Load("AnotherAssembly")
    .GetTypes()
    .Single(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISample)));
ISample instance = (ISample) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
string result = instance.SampleMethod("test");
```

... 
Note how I [cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) the instance to `ISample` -- this removes the need to call `GetMethod`.

If you do not already have a reference to the assembly, you can do this:

```
Type[] types = Assembly
    .Load("AnotherAssembly")
    .GetTypes();
Type sampleInterface = types
    .Single(f => f.Name == "ISample" && f.IsInterface == true);
Type type = types
    .Single(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(sampleInterface));
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("SampleMethod");
string result = (string) method.Invoke(instance, new object[] { "you will see me" });
```

Comment: Hi, I don't referenced another assembly directly, I only load it from file dynamically, How I can use ISample type, interface name is just a string type. Thanks

Comment: @BesLey I updated my answer. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @BesLey Awesome. If this answer answered your question please consider marking it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate an interface but you can find the class implementing it:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadAssembly("AnotherAssemblyFile");
Type[] assemblyTypes = assembly.GetTypes();

Type ISampleType = assemblyTypes.GetType("NameSpace.ISample");

Type sampleType = assemblyTypes.Single(type => 
                  (type != ISampleType) && ISampleType.IsAssignableFrom(type));

object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(sampleType);
MethodInfo mi = sampleType .GetMethod("SampleMethod");
var result = mi.Invoke(instance, new object[]{"you will see me"});
```

Comment: Hi, I used your sample code, ...typeof(ISampleType)..., The type or namespace name 'ISampleType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: It's almost work, but still need to fix. Because there are two types matched it. It will work fine this way.                                                       Type sampleType = anotherAssemblyTypes
                .Single(type => !type.IsInterface && outerInterface.IsAssignableFrom(type));

Comment: @BesLey The other matching type must be ISampleType itself:) I've fixed the code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create instance of interface type, because interface is just an API, it's a contract definition and nothing else. Actually if you'll try to instantiate interface, you'll get exception:

> System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an
>   interface.

So you need to get type which implements your interface and instantiate instance of that type:

```
var anotherAssemblyTypes = Assembly.LoadAssembly("AnotherAssemblyFile").GetTypes();
// get interface type
Type outerInterface = anotherAssemblyTypes
                        .Single(t => t.Name == "ISample" && t.IsInterface);
// find class which implements it
Type outerClass = anotherAssemblyTypes
                        .Single(t => !t.IsInterface && outerInterface.IsAssignableFrom(t));
// instantiate class
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(outerClass);
string result = obj.SampleMethod("Bob");
```

Of course you don't have to use dynamic object here. I used it just to test SampleMethod is called.

Comment: "SampleMehod" is a string variable, but in your last line, you use it directly, it seemed I cant do it by using dynamic style.

Comment: @BesLey that's the exact reason why I wrote note about usage of dynamic for my test only: "I used it just to test SampleMethod is called"

Comment: Great, I see.  It is a nice solution. Thanks